# How to append to dynamic react router url?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

say I have this url `/something/:id/somethingelse/:anotherid/hello`

and I want to change it when I do something to `/something/:id/somethingelse/:anotherid/hello/complete`

if I do `history.push('/complete')` it just overwrites the whole thing so how do I append to it?

also these things are `:id` are obviously dynamic so I just want to append to the url and not lose anything and then once the user refreshes on the new route it stays on that?

Answer (score 0):

solved this by just manually get the window.location.pathname and query params and appending in `/complete` and then pushing the new route

Answer (score 0):

So from the [history documentation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/history.md#history) I have found only the `push` and `replace` function detailed below which are related for changing the URL:

Details about `push`:

> push(path, [state]) - (function) Pushes a new entry onto the history stack

There is a different one called `replace`, maybe you might want to take a look at:

> replace(path, [state]) - (function) Replaces the current entry on the history stack

`VSCode` gives you a hint, so maybe for later usage it is useful to be familiar with `replace`:
[image: Replace function]

You might want to use the `replace` one or of course you can go with a custom solution as you mentioned in your answer.